# What sound does a monkey make?

Tags: onomatopoeia, animals

What is the hiragana sound that monkeys make in Japanese (like わんわん for dogs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[キキー](https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/animal-noises.html) or [ウキウキ／ウキー](https://www.punipunijapan.com/japanese-animal-sounds/). Lots of other pages, too, including [lots of other sounds](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/japanese-onomatopoeia/), too.